# HTTP Post in C# console app doesn't return the same thing as a browser request

Tags: c#, http, post, console-application

I have a C# console app (.NET 2.0 framework) that does an HTTP post using the following code:

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder(100);
postData.Append("post.php?");
postData.Append("Key1=");
postData.Append(val1);
postData.Append("&Key2=");
postData.Append(val2);

byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/");
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

httpRequest.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;
Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
requestStream.Flush();
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

if (httpRequest.HaveResponse == true) {
  Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
  String responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The outputs from this are:
webResponse.ContentLength = -1
webResponse.ContentType = text/html
webResponse.ContentEncoding is blank

The responseString is HTML with a title and body.

However, if I post the same URL into a browser (http://example.com/post.php?Key1=some_value&Key2=some_other_value), I get a small XML snippet like:

`<?xml version="1.0" ?>`
`<RESPONSE RESULT="SUCCESS"/>`

with none of the same HTML as in the application.  Why are the responses so different?  I need to parse the returned result which I am not getting in the HTML.  Do I have to change how I do the post in the application?  I don't have control over the server side code that accepts the post.

Answer (score 10):

If you are indeed supposed to use the `POST` HTTP method, you have a couple things wrong.  First, this line:

```
postData.Append("post.php?");
```

is incorrect.  You want to post *to* `post.php`, you don't want post the value "post.php?" to the page.  Just remove this line entirely.

This piece:

```
... WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/");
```

needs `post.php` added to it, so...

```
... WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/post.php");
```

Again this is assuming you are actually supposed to be `POST`ing to the specified page instead of `GET`ing.  If you are supposed to be using `GET`, then the other answers already supplied apply.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to get an HTTP sniffer tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) and compare the headers that are being sent from your app to the ones being sent by the browser. There will be something different that is causing the server to return a different response. When you tweak your app to send the same thing browser is sending you should get the same response. (It could be user-agent, cookies, anything, but something is surely different.)

Comment: Fiddler rocks, that might be the single most valuable tool I've come across in the last few years.

Comment: Firefox also gives this kind of tool simply type Ctrl+Shift+C then go to Network and you can recover all the packets sent by your browser.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this in the past.

When you run from a browser, the "User-Agent" in the header is "Mozilla ...".

When you run from a program, it's different and generally specific to the language used.

Comment: Why do you think this is the problem?  Do many sites really have different behavior depending on what user-agent you send?

Comment: Yes - e.g. firewall behaviour.

Comment: yes we can add the header like 

requestObject.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR1.0.3705;)");

Answer (score 1):

In your code you a specify the POST method which sends the data to the PHP file without putting the data in the web address.  When you put the information in the address bar, that is not the POST method, that is the GET method.  The name may be confusing, but GET just means that the data is being sent to the PHP file through the web address, instead of behind the scenes, not that it is supposed to get any information.  When you put the address in the browser it is using a GET.

Create a simple html form and specify POST as the method and your url as the action.  You will see that the information is sent without appearing in the address bar.

Then do the same thing but specify GET.  You will see the information you sent in the address bar.

Comment: I disagree with you on the fact that GET's name is confusing as well as its purpose. First off, all HTTP requests 'send' the request then get a response back. This is how it is designed. Although HTTP verbs can be misused, their intended purposes are very clear. GET should only be used to RETRIEVE a resource. The query string you provide should not be altering any data, but provides the server with more information on what kind of data you wish to retrieve. The name GET is very appropriate to me for this purpose. POST is used to update or create a resource.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a GET request, instead of POST.  If the url you're using has querystring values (like ?Key1=some_value&Key2=some_other_value) then it's expecting a GET.  Instead of adding post values to your webrequest, just put this data in the querystring.

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/?val1=" + val1 + "&val2=" + val2);
httpRequest.Method = "GET";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
....
```

So, the result you're getting is different when you POST the data from your app because the server-side code has a different output when it can't read the data it's expecting in the querystring.

Comment: To be clear - in the example `http://example.com/post.php?Key1=some_value&Key2=some_other_value` IS AN HTTP-GET REQUEST, so your code (if it wants the same result) should also do a GET request. To exactly mirror the browser request, dump the `postData` and put the entire Url+Querystring in the WebRequest.Create() (as Kevin says here)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem has something to do with the way your headers are set up for the WebRequest.

I have seen strange cases where attempting to simulate a browser by changing headers in the request makes a difference to the server.

The short answer is that your console application is not a web browser and the web server of example.com is expecting to interact with a browser.

You might also consider changing the ContentType to be "multipart/form-data".

What I find odd is that you are essentially posting nothing.  The work is being done by the query string.  Therefore, you probably should be using a GET instead of a POST.

Answer (score 0):

Is the form expecting a cookie? That is another possible reason why it works in the browser and not from the console app.